# What determines the weather in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm in an area full of snow, does that mean it will only snow, or is there a possibility of rain?

Is an area with ice or snow guaranteed to have snow fall? If not, what decides what weather the area has? Is there a way to tell what weather you will get in an area without having to wait and see?

EDIT:
So, going by the accepted answer, this shouldn't be happening?
[image: Raining on the snow]
[image: Rain on snow]

Clearly, it can rain on areas that were covered by snow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. In an area covered by snow, it will only snow. Weather is controlled by the type of biome it is affecting. It doesn't rain in **Tundra**, **Taiga** and **Desert** biomes.

At the moment, there are two types of weather: Rain and snow. Thunderstorms can occur in both types, and these can be dangerous: striking things with lightning (including you!), creating fires (as a result of the lighting strikes) and etctera. The occurrence of weather lasts for 15 minutes, if you don't want to go through it, you can sleep in a bed to skip that time entirely.

As a proof that different biomes have different types of weather at the same time, see the following image: (courtesy of the Minecraft Wiki)

[image: Minecraft Weather]

More information about weather: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Weather

Comment: Can it only storm where it rains?

Comment: @Nick Thanks, I added more information. Formatting is still poor, though. Looking forward to improve my answers, if you have any suggestion, please say!

Comment: Actually, it does rain in snowy biomes. This may be a bug, but I seem to remember Notch saying in the tweet with that picture that he didn't like the abruptness.